Reactor skip step without Retry
I'm a little confused.
The problem is on making reactive call chain with retry. It goes to step 3 without save retried value on step 2. If I delete onErrorContinue it will retry save successefuly but I miss "onErrorContinue" functionality.
What I do:

Input: Flux
Call repository save for Model in flatMap with Retry on exception
I need to skip SomeModel if it fails on 2 step. (actually it's reactive kafka listener)

just for example
            Flux.fromIterable(s) // actually from kafka
                    .flatMap(kk -> eventService.save(kk)
                        .doOnNext(it -> record.receiverOffset().acknowledge()))                
            .onErrorContinue((ex, record) -> {
                log.error("Exception during consumer", ex);
                if (record instanceof ReceiverRecord failedRecord &&
                        ex instanceof DeserializationException exception) {
                    log.error("Failed record details {} and exception {}", record, exception);
                    failedRecord.receiverOffset().acknowledge();
                } else {
                    log.error("Some unexpected error type! Cant move offset", ex);
                }
            })
            .doOnError(e -> log.error("Exception during consumer", e))
            .retry()
            .subscribe();

eventService.save looks like. And it works as excpected (do retry on exception)
public Mono<SomeModel> save(SomeModel someModel) {
    return Mono.defer(() -> repository.save(someModel))
            .retryWhen(Retry
                    .backoff(1, Duration.ofMillis(100))
                    .maxBackoff(Duration.ofMillis(5000)));

}


What did you actually want to ask?

Actualy exception propagation helped me
public Mono<SomeModel> save(SomeModel someModel) {
    return Mono.defer(() -> repository.save(someModel))
            .retryWhen(Retry
                    .backoff(1, Duration.ofMillis(100))
                    .maxBackoff(Duration.ofMillis(5000)))
                .onErrorContinue((t, o) -> {
                    throw Exceptions.propagate(t);
                }));


The main conflict lies between retry() and onErrorContinue() operators.
The retry() is meant to repeat the entire operation when an error occurs , but onErrorContinue() skips erros without retrying them .
try following code snippet ;

Flux.fromIterable(s) // assuming this is from Kafka
    .flatMap(kk -> eventService.save(kk)
        .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofMillis(100)) // Retry logic
            .filter(ex -> ex instanceof SpecificRetryableException)) // Define retryable exceptions
        .doOnNext(it -> record.receiverOffset().acknowledge())
        .onErrorResume(ex -> { // Handle non-retryable exceptions (skip the record)
            log.error("Skipping record due to error", ex);
            return Mono.empty(); // Skips the record on error
        })
    )
    .onErrorContinue((ex, record) -> {
        log.error("Exception during consumer", ex);
        if (record instanceof ReceiverRecord failedRecord && ex instanceof DeserializationException exception) {
            log.error("Failed record details {} and exception {}", record, exception);
            failedRecord.receiverOffset().acknowledge(); // Skip the record and move the offset
        } else {
            log.error("Some unexpected error type! Can't move offset", ex);
        }
    })
    .doOnError(e -> log.error("Exception during consumer", e))
    .subscribe();




Retry Logic : define within  flatmap , allowing retries for specific exceptions using retrywhen() and a custom filter() to target retryable errors

